# I can not understand, when the left operand of ?? becomes null in below code?

Tags: c#, entity

I know that single `?` is used to make a variable `nullable`, but what does double `??` mean in below code?

```
txtId.Text = Convert.ToDecimal(conn.LeavesRequests.Max(lr => (decimal?)lr.Id) + 1 ?? 1).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

[The ?? operator is called the null-coalescing operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx). It returns the left-hand operand if the operand is not null; otherwise it returns the right hand operand.

Here's the explanation for this operator:

```
int? x = null;
// Set y to the value of x if x is NOT null; otherwise,
// if x = null, set y to -1.
int y = x ?? -1;
```

So if the value of this `Convert.ToDecimal(conn.LeavesRequests.Max(lr => (decimal?)lr.Id) + 1` is null then `txtId.Text` will get value 1 i.e right operand or the evaluated value of `Convert.ToDecimal(conn.LeavesRequests.Max(lr => (decimal?)lr.Id) + 1`

Comment: can include this link too https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx

Answer (score 0):

`expr1 ?? expr2` gives the value of expr1 if expr1 is not null. If it is null, it gives the value of expr2.